# HC-06 bluetooth connected but not responding

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I have a HC-06 Bluetooth module connected to an Arduino Nano.

I can pair the phone to the HC-06, and I can connect it, and the red light from the HC-06 board stops blinking.

But when I try to send any data, it does nothing. I tried to use several Bluetooth apps to send commands to the Bluetooth module, but nothing works.

Do you have any idea what the problem is or how I can debug it further?

I have 2 Hc-06 boards and I tried both, with same result.

Thank you.

I have added my Arduino code blow. I have the D6 pin connected to the RX pin of the HC-06 and the D5 pin to the TX pin:

```
#include <PWMServo.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(6, 5); 

PWMServo myservo;  

String inString = "";

unsigned long startTime;
unsigned long otherTime;

int prev = 150;

float vPow = 5;
float r1 = 47000;
float r2 = 10000;

int voltcheck = 0;

double b = 85; //Braking
double n = 90; //Neutral
double m = 120; //Accelerate

void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  myservo.attach(9);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available() > 0) {
    int inChar = mySerial.read();
    if (isDigit(inChar)) {
      inString += (char)inChar; 
    }
    if (inChar == 'n') {
      int x = inString.toInt();
      if (x <= 180){
        myservo.write(x); 
      }
      inString = "";
    }
    if (inChar == 'm') {
      if (voltcheck > 10){
      getv();
      voltcheck = 0;
      }
      else {
        voltcheck = voltcheck + 1;
      }
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      //Serial.println("ALIVE");
      startTime = millis();
    }
  }
  if ((millis() - startTime) > 210) {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    myservo.write(90); 
    delay(30);
  }
}

static void getv() {
  float v = (analogRead(5) * vPow) / 1023.0;
    float v2 = v / (r2 / (r1 + r2));
    mySerial.print(v2);
    mySerial.println("v");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Arduino code looks for Serial data to appear and responds to it (IE you have code in place to communicate, you just can't get it to respond), try switching the Rx and Tx lines.